# Given a jQuery object in a variable containing the rows of a table, how can I find out how many are visible?

Tags: jquery

I have this JS code :

```
var trs = $("#internalActivities > tbody > tr");
```

I want to be able to use the variable `trs` to find the number of visible rows in the table.

This is the code that I am looking to convert to use the variable

```
$("#internalActivities > tbody > tr:visible").length
```

I am looking for a code like this: `trs:visible.length`. Of course this code won't work but I want the syntax that works.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Won't this work ?

```
trs.filter(":visible").length
```

From the docs:

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

More info here at `filter` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Comment: I just did. I could not mark it earlier because you answer it too quick :) Thanks again